# How to write a prolog query that generates just one answer from the facts that has multiple arities (example below)?

Tags: prolog

Suppose I am writing a prolog `facts.pl` file telling me that software version 1.1 upgrades to software version 1.2 on the following OS's (example below).
But when querying, I am not interested in the entire list of OS's and say for example just want to find if `'Solaris 10'` is supported, how do I write such a query?

```
upgrades('1.1', ['Windows 2008 SP2', 'Windows 2008 R2', 'Windows 2008 R2 SP1', 'SuSE Linux 10', 'SuSE Linux 11', 'RHEL 5.5', 'RHEL 5.8', 'Solaris 10']).
```

Now how do I query if we can upgrade 1.1 to 1.2 on Solaris 10 only?

Comment: I would have a query that says, `upgradeable('Solaris 10', '1.2'). But, I don't see `1.2` mentioned anywhere in your fact(s). Is it just assumed that if something is in the upgrades list for `1.1` that it's upgradeable to `1.2`? What about `1.3`? What is the rule you want to apply to say that an OS is upgradeable? Is it if the upgrade-to version is `.1` greater than the version listed in the facts? Or is it anything greater? Your description for upgradeability isn't complete.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I efficiently design a Prolog fact that has multiple arities?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28093264/how-do-i-efficiently-design-a-prolog-fact-that-has-multiple-arities)

Comment: Please don't repeatedly post the very same question, slightly reworded. Either (A) edit the question to make it clearer or (B) delete the old question.

Comment: Sorry, Lurker and Carey, I should have been a little more clear. I shall henceforth ensure I am clear with my questions. Thanks and appreciate your time looking at this query.

Answer (score 0):

Prolog has a relational data model. So the same 'best practice' apply to data design, as you would use in RDBMS (SQL, let's say)

Where possible, it's better to make small, explicit relations among symbols and values, instead of 'all encompassing' as the one you're showing.

Anyway, assuming you have *another* fact like

```
upgrades('1.2', ['Windows 2008 SP2', 'Windows 2008 R2', 'Windows 2008 R2 SP1', 'SuSE Linux 10', 'SuSE Linux 11', 'RHEL 5.5', 'RHEL 5.8', 'Solaris 10']).
```

then `?- can_upgrade(OS, From, To).` could be

```
can_upgrade(OS, From, To) :-
  upgrades(From, L1), member(OS, L1),
  upgrades(To, L2), member(OS, L2).
```